# Unable to extract every text from an image using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to read the text from an image using openCV and Pytesseract but it seems that I am unable to read everything that is written there in that image either as a plain text or something over logo.

I have done something like this:-

```
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
bw_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('B/W Image', bw_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(bw_img, lang='eng'))
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and what I am getting in return as output:-

Support Local Business & Donate to the
‘COVID-19 CRISIS RESPONSE FUND
frie GREATER EVANSVILLE REGION

SUPPORT

LOCAL

I have attached the images which I am trying to read text from and as you can see the text "ORDER HERE" inside a rectangle shaped button logo is unable to read/extract by openCV.

[image]

On the below images, both Cloud Vision API and Pytesseract are not able to extract proper text out of it. for Image first, I am getting "off club price" and for second " ".
[image]
[image]

If there is any other way to read text in python which is way better or easy than this one, kindly share.

Comment: Invert this image and OCR it.

Comment: Well, you barely pre-process your image...

Comment: You should threshold the image to binary so that you have white letters and black background. Then you should be able to use pytesseract. Or you can find contours and their bounding boxes and extract each roi. Then have pytesseract read it letter by letter. Or word by word. Search Google and you should find many examples. Always do that before asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract doesn't seem to like white text that much. Here is what I get if I run it against your last two images

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('599.jpg', 0)
# img = 255 - img #invert image
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config = '--psm 12'))

print('====================================================')

img = cv2.imread('25off.jpg', 0)
# img = 255 - img #invert image
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config = '--psm 12'))
```

output:

```
so

“I

99
====================================================
vs

25

off

(OP om ilo)
```

not a complete disaster, but not great. Now if you uncomment out the `img = 255 - img` lines, you'll invert the images and the output becomes:

```
5

I)

99
====================================================
%

25

off

Club Price
```

which is much better.